# How to select specific values from randomly selected rows in excel, where one is always larger than the other?

Tags: excel

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

I am trying to get the value from the Years row that is selected and to ensure the Year value in one row is always larger than the other.

This is the code I have tried using
`=INDEX(E5:E36,RANDBETWEEN(1,32))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper cell to get the values. In a cell e.g. (J3), enter the random formula with top value less than the range of 32, such as 31.

`=RANDBETWEEN(1, 31)`.

In the first formula cell reference this helper cell.

`=INDEX(E5:E36,J3)`

In the 2nd formula cell, reference the helper cell for the row value and add 1 so that it's greater than J3.

`=INDEX(E5:E36,RANDBETWEEN(J3+1,32))`

If `J3 = 31`, there would be only 1 cell available for the 2nd formula, but you could adjust the level to a lower number if you wanted to ensure the 2nd number was random.

Comment: Thanks it worked, do you know how I can get the Year value from the same row.

Comment: The random number is matching the Year value in the cells from your example, but if they're not numbered 1-32,  you could use Index on column A instead of E, and use a 2nd helper cell.

Comment: Thanks for the help.